# React JS: How to use responsive styles with react-spring

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby, styled-components, react-spring

I am new to building websites with Gatsby and thus React JS.

### Problem

I want to make a simple animation based on the css `transform` property using `react-spring`.
As I use `styled-components` (with `theme.js` file), I want the animation to be responsive depending on the *breakpoint*.

The problem is that `react-spring` will not accept an *array*, but rather only *strings* as e.g. "10px".

---

✅ **Responsive styles with `react-components`**

Let's say I have following definition

```js
const MyDiv = styled(animated.div)`
  height: 100px;
  ${width}
`;
```

and simply call the element like that

```js
<MyDiv width={[50, 70]} />
```

As I've implemented *breakpoints* in my `theme.js` file, this works perfectly (using *ThemeProvider* from *styled-components*).

✅ **Animation on Button**

Let's define the *spring* animation as follows:

```js
const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState(false);
const clickState = useSpring({
  oi: showButton ? 0 : 1,
});
const divAnimation = {
  transform: clickState.oi.interpolate(oi => `translateX(${oi * 50}px)`),
};
```

and call it as

```js
<Button onClick={setShowButton(!showButton)}>
  <MyDiv style={{ ...divAnimation }} />
</Button>
```

---

❌ **Responsive & animation**

As indirectly mentioned above, I'd like to have a slightly different animation depending on the window width. So, I came up with some ideas how to implement that but none of that works.

The must be a possibility where the animation `divAnimation` shifts the div differently. Or not..?

---

Thanks in advance for your help.

Kind regards

.

.

.

post scriptum: Dependencies of that code

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { width } from 'styled-system';
import { animated } from 'react-spring';¨
import { Button } from 'rebass';
```

Comment: were you ever able to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.matchMedia` to call media queries inside JavaScript, then change your spring's input accordingly.

An example implementation as a custom hook:

```
const useMediaQuery = (minWidth: number) => {
  const [matches, setMatches] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia(
      `screen and (min-width: ${minWidth}px)`
    );
    const listener = (ev) => {
      setMatches(ev.matches);
    };
    mediaQuery.addEventListener("change", listener);

    return () => {
      mediaQuery.removeEventListener("change", listener);
    };
  }, []);

  return matches;
};
```